# How check if a topic exist from cli

Tags: bash, apache-kafka, command-line-interface

I want to check if a topic name 1-codicefiscale-18032022142136-i exist in apache kafka

I use this cli command but it doesn't work

```
     /usr/share/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe / 
     --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 / 
     --replication-factor 1 / 
     --partitions 1 / 
     --topic 1-codicefiscale-18032022142136-i
```

"describe" isn't in shell kafka-topics.sh

Comment: What is the exact error message you get? Why are you providing replication factor or partition count to describe a topic?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, change the "/" symbols as "\". Also you don't need to give replication factor and partitions, you are not creating a topic. Run it as:

```
 /usr/share/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe \
 --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
 --topic 1-codicefiscale-18032022142136-i
```

If the topic does not exsist, you will get an error like `"Topic '1-codicefiscale-18032022142136-i ' does not exist as expected`. If it exists, it will give some information about the topic.